# com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to use navigation components in my fragment but i am having problem inflating my layout using Binding.
see, this is my fragment xml and this is the `fragment.kt` code:

this is the error:

> com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast
> to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_white_color"
    tools:context=".home.presentation.view.EditNoteScreen">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/mine_notes_tittle_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="58dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/new_note"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_text"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/add_new_note_button_home_screen"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent_color"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:src="@drawable/add_note_button_home_screen"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_goneMarginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="24sp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back_button_new_note_screen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent_color"
        android:src="@drawable/back_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mine_notes_tittle_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mine_notes_tittle_text_view" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/new_note_card_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lilac_color"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:theme="@style/CustomCardCorners"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/back_button_new_note_screen">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/newNote_cardTittle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/note_title"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/newNote_cardDescription"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_text"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/newNote_cardTittle" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/tittle_input_text_new_card_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/edit_text_tittle"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/new_note_card_item"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/new_note_card_item" />


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_note_input_tittle_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/type_your_tittle"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/grey_text"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="25"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/grey_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tittle_input_text_new_card_screen">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tittle_input_text_new_card_screen"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tittle_input_text_new_card_screen" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/description_input_text_new_card_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/description_new_note_screen_tittle"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/new_note_input_tittle_edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/new_note_input_tittle_edit_text" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_note_input_description_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/type_your_description"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/grey_text"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="220"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/grey_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description_input_text_new_card_screen">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@id/description_input_text_new_card_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minLines="2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tittle_input_text_new_card_screen"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tittle_input_text_new_card_screen" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/new_note_baby_blue_button"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_button_not_selected"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_baby_color"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/new_note_input_description_edit_text" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/new_note_light_turquoise_button"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_button_not_selected"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/turquoise_color"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/new_note_baby_blue_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/new_note_input_description_edit_text" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/new_note_pastel_purple_button"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_button_not_selected"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_color"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/new_note_light_turquoise_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/new_note_input_description_edit_text" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/new_note_pastel_lilac_button"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_button_not_selected"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lilac_color"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/new_note_pastel_purple_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/new_note_input_description_edit_text" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/new_note_pastel_pink_button"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_button_not_selected"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/pink_color"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/new_note_pastel_lilac_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/new_note_input_description_edit_text" />




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my fragment.kt:

```
package com.example.notesapp.home.presentation.view

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.notesapp.R
import com.example.notesapp.databinding.FragmentNewNoteScreenBinding


class NewNoteScreen : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_new_note_screen) {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentNewNoteScreenBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentNewNoteScreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        setListener()

        return binding.root
    }


    private fun setListener() {
        binding.run {
            backButtonNewNoteScreen.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_newNoteScreen_to_homeScreenfragment)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {

    }
}
```

I would like to know why the error is and how to resolve it so I can continue coding my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are encountering is caused by assigning the same ID, **description_input_text_new_card_screen**, to both a MaterialTextView and a TextInputEditText in your XML layout. This leads to a class cast exception when trying to inflate the layout.

To resolve this issue, you need to assign different IDs to these two elements. Update the ID of either the MaterialTextView or the TextInputEditText in your XML layout to a unique ID.

For example, you can change the ID of the TextInputEditText to new_note_input_text_edit:

Comment: my God! I have not seen it. Thank you very much!!! what a shame xD

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT again.

Comment: why you just blaming it's my own answer just rewrited with it